# Pasting ISO-8859-1 characters into Python IDLE - IDLE changes them

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.6, python-idle

I have some lines in a text document I am trying to replace/remove. The document is in the ISO-8859-1 character encoding.

When I try to copy this line into my Python script to replace it, it won't match. If I shorten the line and remove up until the first double quotation mark " it will replace it fine.

i.e.

```
desc = [x.replace('Random text “^char”:', '') for x in desc]
```

This will not match. If I enter:

```
desc = [x.replace('Random text :', '') for x in desc]
```

It matches fine. I have checked that it isn't the ^ symbol as well. 
Clearly Python IDLE is not using the same character set as my text file and is changing the symbol when I paste it into the script. So how do I get my script to look for this line if it doesn't handle the same characters?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? It's very important to mention that in questions relating to encoding issues, since there are major differences between Python 2 & Python 3 in how they handle Unicode.

Comment: I don't think your document is using ISO-8859-1 since that encoding doesn't have `“` or `”`. However, it's _very_ common for text encoded with Windows codepage 1252 to be mislabelled as ISO-8859-1, as mentioned in the Wikipedia article on [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.0. How do I tell what actual encoding the document is using? Is there a way to get the character to paste into my script once I know what it is for sure?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no sure-fire way to determine the encoding of a plain text document, although there are packages that can make very good guesses by analyzing the contents of the document. Do those "smart" quotes  `“` and `”` get turned into `â` when you paste them into your script? If not, what _do_ they become?

Comment: I can't actually replicate it by pasting it here. When I copy them into my script the become similar to " but at an angle pointing towards the words they go around

Comment: Hmmm. One popular 3rd-party module for encoding detection is [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet). It will probably work on your document, but as I said earlier there are no guarantees. I'll post some code that shows how to do the replacement once you have determined the correct encoding.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you did.  Where did you copy from? Where did you paste?  On what system? Windows? Your python assignment statement is executed by Python, not IDLE, so this may have nothing to do with IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no sure-fire way to determine the encoding of a plain text document, although there are packages that can make very good guesses by analyzing the contents of the document. One popular 3rd-party module for encoding detection is [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet). Or you could manually use trial and error with some popular encodings and see what works.

Once you've determined the correct encoding, the replacement operation itself is simple in Python 3. The core idea is to pass the encoding to the `open` function, so that you can write Unicode string objects to the file, or read Unicode string objects from the file. Here's a short demo. This will work correctly if the encoding of your terminal is set to UTF-8. I've tested it on Python 3.6.0, both in the Bash shell and in idle3.6.

```
fname = 'test.txt'
encoding = 'cp1252'

data = 'This is some Random text “^char”: for testing\n'
print(data)

# Save the text to file
with open(fname, 'w', encoding=encoding) as f:
    f.write(data)

# Read it back in
with open(fname, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
    text = f.read()

print(text, text == data)

# Perform the replacement
target = 'Random text “^char”:'

out = text.replace(target, 'XXX')
print(out)
```

**output**

```
This is some Random text “^char”: for testing

This is some Random text “^char”: for testing
 True
This is some XXX for testing
```